# How to fix Unauthorized access on POST /oauth/token

Tags: laravel, api, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, laravel-5.4

I am trying to make demo of SPA app in Vue.js which communicates with backend API made in laravel 5.4 with passport and oauth.
I am passing along with tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEn16aQoowE&list=PLkZU2rKh1mT9TgMvpFY1QVrX2z4I3D3Jq&index=1

The only difference is that my backend API has Custom User Provider to simulate autehntication to another database table via table view.

POST to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token` gives me following eror:

> Response {url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token", ok: false, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", headers: Headers…}

Here is how to reproduce it:

1. Setup backend API:

   `git clone https://github.com/gandra/laravel54-passport-demo-external-user
   cd laravel54-passport-demo-external-user
   cp .env.example .env
   composer install
   php artisan key:generate
   npm install
   npm run dev
   php artisan migrate
   php artisan db:seed
   php artisan passport:install`
2. Update your `laravel54-passport-demo-external-user/.env` file with your database info
3. Bring up API server with:

   `php artisan serve`
4. Setup frontend:

   `git clone https://github.com/gandra/laravel54-passport-demo-vue-client.git
   cd laravel54-passport-demo-vue-client
   npm install`
5. Update client secret in `laravel54-passport-demo-vue-client\src\App.vue` with value of `secret` field from table `oauth_clients` where name = 'Laravel Password Grant Client'
6. Bring up frontend:

   `npm run dev`

   This should open url `http://localhost:8080/` in browser. Open browser console and check for error. You will see something like this:

[image]

Here is the error log from laravel: 
https://gist.github.com/gandra/f3a45a638df036e280303ff6d94a89d0
and another one when tried with other client: 
https://gist.github.com/gandra/8da758ad223916613c0604817c2e1130

Comment: `League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::invalidClient()` would indicate that the client you're using is incorrect? Double check your client IDs in your env, and make sure they exist in the database. I haven't used Passport in a while so I'm not 100% sure about it, but hopefully that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @PhilCross,
but I checked it few times. I have added another gist. The first one you have seen is when I have been trying with another client. Sop now I am getting error that the user credentials were incorrect but I can succesfully login on http://127.0.0.1:8000/login with the same credentials. The same error from POSTMAN: http://i.imgur.com/CgiA0PR.png